# Ending of Zach Stone Is Gonna Be Famous

Tags: plot-explanation, zach-stone

Does anyone know why in the last scene when Zack is being asked for his autograph, Amy puts this sad/serious face?

Is it because he is gonna be crazy again about being famous or because she just kissed him so he becomes more famous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, it's because she's worried Zack caught the fame bug again.** From the [Wikipedia episode synopsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zach_Stone_Is_Gonna_Be_Famous):

> Everyone (including Zach and Amy) begin chanting "Zach! Zach! Zach!" After this, the crowd members ask him to sign autographs
>   and to take pictures with them. As Zach does this, he starts singing "Zach Stone Is Gonna Be Famous" to himself. **The final shot of the show shows a close up on Amy's face as she watches this unfold. The smile she has had since the beginning of the previous scene slowly begins to fade towards a disappointed, saddened expression. She knows that, what with all of this fame and recognition, that Zach is probably going to go back to his old ways within time.**

So this was either intended as a bitter-sweet ending, or an attempt to maintain some of the main premise for next season - but the show was unfortunately cancelled, so we'll never know for sure which.

Comment: Thanks! What a pitty about the cancellation... love that comedian ^^